# SQL Avoid multiplication on inner joins with several returns

Tags: sql

OK, not the best title but could not explain it better.

I have a SQL query with a line like this.

```
count(PRStatusChangesLog.EffectiveMinutes) as timeInHandoverExternal
```

it works so far but I also want to add something like this
`COUNT (distinct a.ActionId) as 'Number Of Actions'`,

which requires this

```
INNER JOIN PRAction a on a.PrId = PRHeader.prid
```

Now the problem which I am sure some of you have already seen. The previous count is now multiplied by the number of actions.

I can see why this happens but I am not sure how best to do this so I can get both the number of actions and the right count without the multiplier.

Simplified full query

```
SELECT  
    PRHeader.PrId,
    COUNT (distinct a.ActionId) AS 'Number Of Actions',
    COUNT (PRStatusChangesLog.EffectiveMinutes) AS timeInHandoverExternal
FROM         
    PRHeader
LEFT JOIN 
    PRStatusChangesLog ON PRStatusChangesLog.PrId = PRHeader.PrId 
                       AND PRStatusChangesLog.StatusId = 4100
INNER JOIN 
    PRAction a ON a.PrId = PRHeader.prid
WHERE
    DATEDIFF(mm, prheader.ClosedDate, getdate()) = 1  
    AND (PRHeader.siteId = 74)
    AND prheader.PRTypeId IN (17, 19) 
    AND PRHeader.tmpStatusId <> 6010
GROUP BY  
    PRHeader.PrId
```

Comment: Can you share a full query? It's a bit hard to answer this question without something concrete to look at

Comment: Specify your sample data and expected result for make easy to answer for all

Comment: OK added a smimplified full query that highlights the problem

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can count a unique column with `DISTINCT` like `COUNT(DISTINCT PRStatusChangesLog.id)`.
2. If this is not possible use a subquery for counting the actions. In the `SELECT` clause you should write something like: `(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.ActionId) FROM ... WHERE PRAction a on a.PrId = PRHeader.prid) AS action_count`

Comment: You are right!, A simple distinct did the trick, I had tried it but in the wrong place and thought I coulnd't use it in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Using select statement clause in joins to get counts individually then add with final outer select statement.

```
SELECT 
    PRHeader.PrId, Count1 'Number Of Actions', Count2 timeInHandoverExternal
FROM 
    PRHeader 
JOIN 
    (SELECT COUNT (ActionId) Count1 
     FROM PRAction 
     GROUP BY PrId) A ON A.PrId = PRHeader.prid
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         COUNT(PRStatusChangesLog.EffectiveMinutes) Count2, PrId, StatusId  
     FROM 
         PRStatusChangesLog 
     WHERE 
         StatusId = 4100 
     GROUP BY 
         PrId, StatusId) B ON B.PrId = PRHeader.PrId 
WHERE 
    DATEDIFF(mm, prheader.ClosedDate, getdate()) = 1  
    AND (PRHeader.siteId = 74 )
    AND prheader.PRTypeId IN (17,19) 
    AND PRHeader.tmpStatusId <> 6010
```